# Callout box in text field

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to summon a callout box on a button next to a textfield or inside the textfield?

[image]

Or is UIAlertView my only choice?

Edit: With my successful attempt at creating a UIPopoverController, is there a method to position the arrow so that it does not appear in the center?

Comment: What has been seen, cannot be unseen.

Comment: UIPopoverController - but really, rethink you UI

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Comment: random question by WrightCS gets a click on the arrow since he made me laugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully achieved my goal of creating a callout box as it appears in the image of my question. I'd like to thank Paul Cezanne for mentioning a solution for me to pursue. I guess the name (pop over/callout) is different if it is not displayed in a map view. Anyways, for future apple developers, here are the steps I took that answered my question:

1. Embed your first view controller with a navigation controller
2. Keep auto layout and size classes checked in the File Inspector tab on the right hand side in your main storyboard, because the pop over will just act as a push view if we shrink the view controller.
3. Add a second view controller (you do not need to create a header nor an implementation file)
4. Drag a button onto the first view controller (you do not need to create an IBAction)
5. Hold the control key and click and drag from your button on the first view controller to your second controller and the segue choices should appear
6. Select 'Present As Popover'
7. Don't forget to create an identifier for the segue

Now heading over to coding, here is the header file of the view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Here is the implementation file of the view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Declare a string to identify the segue
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;

    // If the string matches the string inside @""
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"popOverSegue"]) {

        // Assign the view controller to a pointer
        UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;

        // Identify that the view controller is to be a pop over presentation controller
        UIPopoverPresentationController *ppc = dvc.popoverPresentationController;

        // Set the size of the view controller
        // Width = 200
        // Height = 200
        dvc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

        // Have the pop over presentation controller point upwards
        ppc.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

        if (ppc) {

            ppc.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {

    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Build and Run and you should have a successful pop over controller app. Fin.